# k3b and brasero rejects attempts to burn Blu-Ray disks on kubuntu 17.04

Tags: burning, blu-ray

Running kubuntu 17.04 on machine that includes an LG WH16NS40 with firmware version 1.02 (apparently latest version).

I'm attempting to burn a 12.0 GB ISO image onto either 25 GB or 50 GB BD-R disks in the above Blu-Ray drive.  K3b in the Burn Image dialog reports the disk as being empty and having 23.3 GiB free space (for a 25 GB BD-R), and thus allows me to start the burn.  Yet, when I attempt to burn the BD-R, K3b reports:

```
Found medium: Empty BD-R medium
Please insert an empty medium of size 12.0 GiB or larger into drive
HL-DT-ST BD-RE WH16NS40 (/dev/sr1)
```

K3b and Gnome Disk Utility correctly detect this drive as a Blu-Ray drive.  The odd thing is that Gnome Disk Utility reports the volume size as 2.0 KB; I would have expected it to show 23.3 or 25 GB for this disk.

I get similar results from Brasero.

Kernel log:

```
Oct  7 12:52:50 computername kernel: [885498.272741] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#28 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Oct  7 12:52:50 computername kernel: [885498.272752] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#28 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
Oct  7 12:52:50 computername kernel: [885498.272755] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
Oct  7 12:52:50 computername kernel: [885498.272756] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 0
Oct  7 12:52:50 computername kernel: [885498.272760] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 0, async page read
Oct  7 12:52:50 computername kernel: [885498.289014] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 0, async page read
```

Does anyone know what's up?  Do I need to supply more information in order to figure this out?

Comment: Try different brand BD-R media. Also try and burn a standard DVD-R just to confirm that you don't have a hardware problem.

Comment: I have two BD-R media:  Verbatim (Taiwan) 50 GB and Optodisk (Taiwan) 25 GB discs; both fail in the same way.  I haven't tried to burn a DVD-R but I have successfully burnt a CD-R on this drive.  I installed the drive less than a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

The K3B refusal and message is a known bug:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381074

solved by the non-Debug parts of

https://cgit.kde.org/k3b.git/commit/?id=329c969be1dbc3455d65925bcad32f4df3a5b428

It simply never accepted BD media for the job of image writing.
Data composition + burning worked with BD.

For diagnosing the problem with Basero one would need more tangible
information.

Gnome Disk Utility might show the readable size of the blank medium
(but then showing 2 KB too many).

The kernel messages are normal with blank media. (Not enough brain to
refrain from trying to read it.)

If you are willing to use the shell command line, try this for burning:

```
xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr1 fs=32m -eject /...path.../my_image.iso
```

with your ISO image file path instead of  /...path.../my_image.iso .

Comment: Your command-line command seemed to work.  After mounting /dev/sr1 to /cdrom, running "diff --recursive" between the mounted BD drive and the directory tree backed up in the ISO file I burned resulted in either expected diffs or the fact that I didn't explicitly include dot files/directories.  I'll see what I can do to figure out why Brasero doesn't work.  Thanks for the info on k3b.  I noticed that /dev/cdrom is linked to /dev/sr0 not sr1, if that makes any difference.  Thank you for your help.  At least I know the hardware, drivers, and command-line software works.